# Cannot convert image to Bytes - Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello im getting an error when I try to convert File to Bytes. Idk what to do ;)

```
        onTap: () async {
          _pickedImage =
              await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
          File _imageFile = File(_pickedImage.path);
          ByteData bytes = await _imageFile
              .readAsBytes()
              .then((data) => ByteData.view(data as ByteBuffer));
```

**ERROR OUTPUT**

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: TypedDataView(cid: 148)
#0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:687:7)
#1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:768:7)
#2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:723:21)
#3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:678:9)
#4      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:876:17)
#5      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:861:5)
#6      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:261:30)
#7      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:171:45)
#8      _RegisterFormScreenState.uploadPictureApiCall (package:korki/register_form_screen.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      _RegisterFormScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:korki/register_form_screen.dart:142:38)
#10     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:945:19)
#11     _InkResponseState.bui<…>
```

Comment: You are trying to convert UintList8 to ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant convert UinitList8 to Bytebuffer directly. But it does provides getter to convert it to the later

```dart
onPressed: () async {
   _pickedImage = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
   _imageFile = File(_pickedImage.path);
   ByteData bytes = await _imageFile
         .readAsBytes()
         // change here
         .then((Uint8List data) => ByteData.view(data.buffer));

},
```